# How to check current element's attribute on Vue.js class binding?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm a total noob on Vue.js and I'm trying to build some kind of <s>pretty</s> customized options selector.

My data-binding works fine but I can not figure out how class-binding works for checking each node's value.

HTML:

```
<div id="pretty_options">
  <ul class="pretty-options" data-field="field_id">
    <li class="option" v-on:click="select" v-bind:class="{ selected : isSelected }" data-value="1">One</li>
    <li class="option" v-on:click="select" v-bind:class="{ selected : isSelected }" data-value="2">Two</li>
    <li class="option" v-on:click="select" v-bind:class="{ selected : isSelected }" data-value="3">Three</li>
    <li class="option" v-on:click="select" v-bind:class="{ selected : isSelected }" data-value="4">Four</li>
    <li class="option" v-on:click="select" v-bind:class="{ selected : isSelected }" data-value="5">Five</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="number" id="field_id" name="field_id" v-model="field_id">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var mcveSample = new Vue({
  el: '#pretty_options',
  data: {
    field_id: 1
  },
  methods: {
    select: function(event) {
      var option = event.currentTarget;
      var value = option.dataset.value;
      this.field_id = value;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isSelected: function(element) {
      // I'd like to do something like this:
      // return this.field_id == element.dataset.value;
      // But, I can't find how to check each element's value...
    }
  }
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jordinebot/0kgth8yL/).

So, my question is: How do I compare with every node's value/attribute on a computed function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computed property returns a value based on another data property or computed value. In your case you should use a method which accepts a `li` index as an argument and returns true/false, or just check equality inline.

Also, you can use `v-for` to generate list items:

```js
var mcveSample = new Vue({
  el: '#pretty_options',
  data: {
    field_id: 0,
    options: ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
  },
  methods: {
    select: function(index) {
      this.field_id = index;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.option {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 1em;
  cursor: default;
}
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    
<div id="pretty_options">
    <ul class="pretty-options" data-field="field_id">
      <li class="option" 
        v-for="(option, index) of options" // create li from your array
        v-on:click="select(index)" 
        v-bind:class="{ selected : index == field_id }" // check inline for example
        v-bind:data-value="index">{{ option }}</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="number" id="field_id" name="field_id" v-model="field_id">
</div>
```

If you prefer `method` and/or you need more complex logic, you can do it like this:

```
v-bind:class="{ selected : isSelected(index) }"
```

And define this method:

```
methods: {
  isSelected: function(index) {
    return index == this.field_id
  },
//...other methods
}
```

or it is better to use computed property which returns function

```
computed:{
  isSelected: function() {
    return function(index){
       return index == this.field_id;
    }
  },
  //...other computed propertues
}
```

[Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)

> computed properties are cached based on their dependencies

Comment: Thank you so much for this broad explanation!

Comment: Excuse me, wostex. I'm implementing it now and I face another issue... What if I can't use a `v-for` (options rendered in server side) or an `index` (`data-value` being a string also rendered server side...)

Comment: @JordiNebot well, `select` will still work, but you need to pass your index to `isSelected` somehow. If you want to render template on server I guess you can hardcode indexes: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/uvon90La/ It's not very optimal though.

Comment: This is a great answer!